# How to implement business rule with dependencies in DDD

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design

Im testing out Domain Driven Development, but need some guidance on how to implement business rules when the business rules has dependencies outside the aggregate.

Im doing this in Java, with Spring Boot and JPA annotations.

Ok, simple example. Lets say we have a domain object aggregate: *Car*

The *Car* has a *Category* (and also lots of other entities related not listed here)

The Category is a entity and a aggregate of its own. The database contains all available and acceptable Categories. There is a CategoryRepository available. The Category contains of an auto-generated id, a unique categoryCode and a description.
The categoryRepository lets you find category by categoryCode.

Now lets consider a "simple" business rule. Update of the Car entity from a Car DTO.
Car DTO contains new car information, and also new categoryCode.

So i`ve created a method Car.update(CarDTO). This Car entity method is a update method that takes a CarDTO as input and then sets the new values on the Car entity.

And here is the problem. The CarDTO contains the categoryCode, not the categoryId or the category-entity. And in the Car object, i must set a Category object for category, not the categoryCode.
So then, either the Car object must have a dependency on categoryRepository in order to resolve the correct Category entity from the category code, or i must find another solution.

How to solve such problems where the business rule has dependencies?

Comment: Why can't you pass Update the Category ID instead of the code?

Comment: @guillaume31 the categoryCode is coming from outside system api. categoryId is only internal in system. But yes, currently the solution is to first process DTO in service layer and add categoryID before it is passed on to the domain object for final processing.

Comment: Yes, that's what's expected - aggregates manipulate other aggregates' IDs. If you get another kind of pointer as an input, it's the application service's job to find the corresponding ID, not the domain object's job.

Comment: @guillaume31 yes i feel this is the most appropriate way i have heard of so far. So i will go for this for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have code that can't be fulfilled by an entity/aggregate you should move this code to a service:

From Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design:

> Service
>
> When an operation does not conceptually belong to any object.
> Following the natural contours of the problem, you can implement these operations in services.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some misunderstandings in your problem statement.

First, Spring and JPA have nothing to do with DDD. What's more, I would consider them almost mutually exclusive. A JPA Entity is not synonymous with a DDD Entity. The first is a database ORM technology, and the second is some part of the business domain (the exact opposite of "technology").

This explains the curious statement of your business rule too: "Update of the Car entity from a Car DTO". I doubt any business person would frame requirements that way, or even understand it when heard.

What is meant by "domain-driven", is really that things in your application should speak the business language. Anything your business counterpart, users or any person sufficiently familiar with your use-case understands or knows should be codified in your code *and nothing more*.

This also means, that technical stuff, that only we developers would understand should be hidden behind business-oriented classes, method names and interfaces.

Try to restate the problem in business terms, concentrate on the language, watch for behavior in your objects instead of data, and your problem may solve itself. Why? Because if the business problem can be stated in a reasonably consistent manner, than your code should automatically be consistent. If it can not, than it's not a technical issue.

Comment: Yes i agree with parts of this. But part of DDD/MDD is to put business logic inside domain model. So what happens when you got a buisiness rule that has dependencies outside the domain aggregate? That is my question.

Comment: That can not be answered objectively. Depends. On what you mean by those words exactly, and what the actual problem is. Since `CarDTO` is not something that would exist in a domain, it's hard for me to translate your example to something I can relate to. Hence my suggestion to model your problem correctly first.